# What does it mean by disk?

Tags: virtualbox, 20.04, disk

I keep getting the please reset blah blah by pressing enter and I need to “eject” a disk but I don’t have a USB or disk in my pc what does it mean

Comment: With the exact message you're talking about, we can only guess. My guess is it's talking about the install media (be it cd/dvd/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/file-on-disk/cd-card/compact-flash or anything else used to store the ISO file). It will vary on your environment too, which is virtualbox from your tag.

Comment: Ah I see (btw what exactly is install media I have a idea of what it is but I’m new to this type of thing and kinda dumb to stuff like this)

Comment: ^ Without the exactly message.. sorry typo...  Refer the answer by @Gryu.  My guess was the install media used to install Ubuntu (you didn't given details of what you're trying to do). On some versions you only need press <Enter> and everything is done for you (it ejects automatically), but this will likely depend on your VirtualBox version, Host Settings and possibly host OS (all of which are unspecified). I've mainly run VirtualBox on Ubuntu or GNU/Linux hosts and rarely need to do anything other than pressing <Enter>

Answer (score 5):

guiverc is right. You need to **Remove Disk from Virtual Drive**:

[image]

[image]